# MySQL Server load

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a Facebook application build with PHP/MySQL, both are installed in the same server.

The server have a high load now, and I want to order a new server only for MySQL Server, Server stats today :

> 4.5 M Queries / day.
>
> 164.57 k Queries / hour.
>
> 2.74 k Queries / minute.
>
> 45 Queries / sec.

What is the best server hardware configuration for a dedicated to handle the triple of this traffic ?

Best Regards,

Comment: Depends largely on 2 factors.  Your read/write ratio and how your data set itself scales.  Can you provide more information?

Comment: You may be better off refactoring your code to make sure it is at it's most efficient form. Apologies in advance if it is streamlined, but 4.5M Queries / day sounds a lot... Even if this is an enterprise solution.

Comment: What @JD says. You may also be able to cache stuff. Maybe not *that*
 much seeing as it's an app, but still.

Comment: First of all congratulations for the good traffic.. :) Refactoring the code would be the best solution here.. Please head over to these screencasts: http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails They are specifically for Rails and most of the screen casts talk about Enhancing SQL queries to scale.. This might be a good start to begin with..

Comment: Agree with JD, code optimizations get you WAY further than hardware. I'd do that first, order hardware after analyzing your future goals and determining what you need. For PHP, definitely install APC. Probably implement memcached; which will help to not repeat queries likely to return the same data within small time windows. Overall, minimize queries. Likely, you'll want 2 new servers, separate the db. Btw, [this performance blog](http://mysqlperformanceblog.com) is a great resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I optimized the php code, and I started to use eaccelerator and a load balancing solution :)
Thanks very much for help!